# Auto Pairing of iPhone with Toyota Prius

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, car-integration

Every time I want to connect an iPhone to the Toyota Prius, I have to do the following:

1. On the Prius, go to the audio screen, then select the bluetooth tab.
2. Press the connect button.
3. On the iPhone, go to Settings > General > Bluetooth and tap the connection to the car.
4. Wait until the two pair, then exit their respective screens.

Isn't there a way to have the two pair up automatically as they detect one another?

Comment: My neww iPhone 4 will NOT connect to the Prius about 90% of the time. I often have to try and connect numerous times just to get one friggin' connection. This was not an issue with the iPhone 3. It bothers me that Apple will not address this issue. They know about it. I have tried everything, and a delay of xx number of seconds makes no difference whatsover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Our Toyota RAV4 is not at home right now, otherwise I would go look in the manual to see what I did).

I know for our Toyota RAV4, that I was able to automatically pair my wife's iPhone with the car so that each time the car is turned on (and the iPhone is in range of the car), the bluetooth system takes over and lets us answer the phone through the car.

My suggestion is to look in your owner's manual and look up how to affect a default pairing. When my RAV4 comes home in a few hours, I can look up the steps we used.

Comment: I deleted both devices that were paired. I then paired the iPhone and made sure that auto connect was on. Now whenever I turn on the car, it connects to the iPhone automatically after 25 seconds or so. Do you also notice this same delay or does it work immediately for you?

Comment: I've never actually tested the pairing time. I have never had a case (so far) where I have started the car and immediately tried to dial out. Glad you were able to make it work.

Comment: Just bought a 2012 Prius C One. It also has a delay of about ten seconds when connecting to the phone. However, I have noticed some sort of delay with every Bluetooth device we connect to our iPads and iPhones. Anywhere from 3 to 10 seconds; reminds me of the old dial-up modem handshake delay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just keep your iPhone in your pocket (or wherever you like) BUT MAKE SURE BLUETOOTH IS ON. Then inside the car, just touch the monitor and select bluetooth. You will find your iPhone already registered there (you can register up to 10 Phones in the Toyota Prius).
So once you click bluetooth, choose your iPhone name, and it will automatically pair.

Unfortunately, the car doesn't provide any other easiest option than this.

Answer (score 0):

I paired my iPhone 6+ without problems. I upgraded to a 7+ and I too could not get it to work via Bluetooth.

I learned, besides pairing my iPhone which *did* work, you also have to push the Setup button and configure the AUDIO to work with Bluetooth.

Once I did that it worked like a charm after I push the AUX button.